# Draw and refresh two independent windows with pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to draw two graphs in two different windows, but I want the graphics that may be dynamically updated.

This code is an example.

Why does it only draws on one of the windows?

How to solve?

Thank you

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
fig_norm = plt.figure()
fig.show()
fig_norm.show()
ax_fig = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax_fig_norm = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax_fig.set_title("Figure 1", fontsize='large')
ax_fig_norm.set_title("Figure Normalized", fontsize='large')

plt.ion()

while True:
    x = np.random.rand(100)
    y = np.random.rand(100)
    ax_fig.plot(x, y)
    ax_fig_norm.plot(x*3, y*3)
    fig.canvas.draw()
    fig_norm.canvas.draw()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `add_subplot` creates an Axes object on the figure which its called on.

You call it on `fig` twice, so obtain the same Axes object.

Please, try:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
fig_norm = plt.figure()
fig.show()
fig_norm.show()
ax_fig = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax_fig_norm = fig_norm.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax_fig.set_title("Figure 1", fontsize='large')
ax_fig_norm.set_title("Figure Normalized", fontsize='large')

plt.ion()

while True:
    x = np.random.rand(100)
    y = np.random.rand(100)
    ax_fig.plot(x, y)
    ax_fig_norm.plot(x*3, y*3)
    fig.canvas.draw()
    fig_norm.canvas.draw()
```